# sql helper class get module for the procedures that return multiple values

Tags: c#-4.0, stored-procedures, sqlhelper

I've written a module in my sql helper class which returns DataSet from the stored procedure.

```
// public class SqlHelper
 public DataSet ExecuteDataSet(string commandText, SqlParameter[] sqlParameter)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(commandText, this.conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddRange(sqlParameter);
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            sda.Fill(ds);
            return ds;
        }
```

But my stored procedure has multiple return outputs. My above module is not working with procedure having output values.

How can I write a module in sql helper class that can handle outputs from the stored procedure.

Comment: Do you mean it has formal output parameters or that it returns multiple resultsets?

Comment: The procedure has output parameters 
`CREATE procedure [dbo].[p_user_records]
(
 @user_name     varchar(20), 
 @v_out_status   char output,
 @v_out_activity   varchar(50) output
)
as
begin
 // procedure logic
end`